# IPCCLEAN command not found

Tags: linux, postgresql, fedora

I have problem with start PostgreSQL server. When I try to start server write this error:

> FATAL:  could not write lock file "postmaster.pid": No space left on
>   device

I found solution by use command `ipcclean` to clear memory. But when i try to use this command system say Command not found.

Can somebody help me? )

Comment: `df -h` will reveal the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of disk space (No space left on device) and not likely out of memory so cleaning IPC memory does not help.

Find what is taking up disk space and free some. You could try removing old log files first.

Consider allocating more disk space.

Answer (score 2):

`ipcclean` is an obsolete PostgreSQL script that disappeared after the 8.3 version (no longer maintained itself). Its [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-ipcclean.html) in 8.3 mentions:

> Since postgres can now clean up by itself, it is unlikely that
>   ipcclean will be improved upon in the future.

and in fact, it was removed.

Anyway, as [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22933959/238814), `No space left on device` means that the disk is full and `ipcclean` wouldn't help with that even if you had postgres 8.3 or older.